# Scroll bar for dynamic content inside a div block in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the UI of the existing RSS reader using jquery, but when trying to put dynamic contents inside the div block, the scroll bar is not working. It seems to  only work with static contents. Please suggest solutions.

Note: (since I am new to jquery explanations are welcomed)

Comment: Some code examples perhaps? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Ilia, i hav tried several combinations of code which is available on goolgle, it seems working well in browser, but when checking in device (Phone and tablet) it, doesn't work for dynamic contents, ie for Google RSS news.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to specify an overflow in CSS for that element.

```
#mydiv {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried the above mentioned code. it's not working.I am trying to integrate Jquery in android(2.3) devices.I have divided the screen into 4 blocks using div class, n i need to bring the google news inside these blocks. plz help.

Comment: css code  .ui-grid-a,.ui-grid-b,.ui-grid-c,.ui-grid-d {
    overflow: auto;
}

Comment: html code <div class="ui-grid-b" id=category>
        
            <div class="ui-block-a" id=block>
            
                 <div>TopNews</div>
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height: 300px" id="TopNews"></div>
            </div></div>

Comment: HI mr. Radio , as i have already mentioned it works for static contents, i have to fetch the news dynamically from google server.

Comment: Good. Now we can close this question by you accepting an answer.